# How can i define, different HTML content for different "user rights"?

Tags: php, html

```
   function settings ()
 {
if (!checkRights(2)) {
    showRightsInfo();
}
if (checkRights(4)) {
    assign("STAMMDATENSTYLE", "");
    assign("ADMINSTYLE", "");
}
if (checkRights(3)) {
    assign("STAMMDATENSTYLE", "");
    ("ADMINSTYLE", "display: none;");
} else {
    ("STAMMDATENSTYLE", "display: none;");
    ("ADMINSTYLE", "display: none;");
}
("PAGETITLE", "Einstellungen");
("MAINPAGE", "a_settings");
("settings");
```

}

So i have this code function settings, which is executed why i want to see the settings in my program. My available rights are 1,2,3,4: where 4 should show everything and 3 only "stammdatenstyle".
My function checkRights() returns me if the rights of the current logged in user are higher than the requested rights. I am desperately trying to change my code because I only added a 4th. rights group which can see everything and before "group" 3 was able to see everything. Where is the problem? Do i have an error in my settings()?

```
 <div class="panel panel-default" style="{STAMMDATENSTYLE}">
 (....)


 <div class="panel panel-default" style="{ADMINSTYLE}">
 (....)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your falling through the various `if` conditions and the last if says if = 3 then do this else do this.  So condition 4 will get overwritten by this last set of settings.

The way I would do it is to set the default values to start with and then adjust the ones you want to...

```
function settings ()
{
    if (!$this->ctb->checkRights(2)) {
        $this->ctb->showRightsInfo();
    }
    $this->ctb->tpl->assign("STAMMDATENSTYLE", "display: none;");
    $this->ctb->tpl->assign("ADMINSTYLE", "display: none;");
    if ($this->ctb->checkRights(4)) {
        $this->ctb->tpl->assign("STAMMDATENSTYLE", "");
        $this->ctb->tpl->assign("ADMINSTYLE", "");
    }
    if ($this->ctb->checkRights(3)) {
        $this->ctb->tpl->assign("STAMMDATENSTYLE", "");
    } 

    $this->ctb->tpl->assign("PAGETITLE", "Einstellungen");
    $this->ctb->tpl->parse("AUSSCHUSSMAINPAGE", "ausschuss_settings");
    $this->buildPage("settings");
}
```

You could also change to use `if() .. elseif... else...` but make sure you get the right combinations.

Comment: Thank you, i've put the if(4) at the end and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

you have the following if/else construct:

```
if(condition){
 // something
}

if(condition){
 // something
}else{
 // something
}
```

this will cause problems surely. as you can see, if the first if-condition is met and the second is not met it will execute two parts of the script, instead of one.

Example:

```
$color = 'blue';

if($color == 'blue'){
 echo 1;
}

if($Color == 'green'){
 echo 2;
}else{
 echo 3;
}
```

This will output 1 and 3 and this is how your current script works.

Therefore you should use at least something like elseif

```
if(condition){
 // something
}elseif(condition){
 // something
}else{
 // something
}
```

but I recommend you to use switch

```
switch(condition){
 case 1:
  // something;
  break;
 case 2:
  // something;
  break;
 case 3:
  // something;
  break;
 case 4:
  // something;
  break;
 default:
  // something
}
```